# Laravel - Add Route Wildcard to every Route

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I have created a multilanguage application in laravel and for every route (because i want to see in the url what my language is) i need

```
www.example.com/{locale}/home
```

for example, whereas {locale} is the set language and home well, is home. but for every route i need to declare that locale wildcard. is there any way to get this done with middleware or something, to add this before route is executed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use prefix for it.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function () {
    Route::get('home','Controller@method');
    Route::get('otherurl','Controller@method');
});
```

And here how you can access it now.

```
www.example.com/{locale}/home 
www.example.com/{locale}/otherurl
```

For more info.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: Sorry , my mistake, the answer is correct but for a question i kind of spelled wrong. I want users to enter /home , and laravel to automatically set the {locale} which is set by the default browser language to prepend to the home url so : I type www.example.com/home , and in the browser url it will be www.example.com/en/home

Comment: Please check this will work I Checked in my local https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-prefixing-in-routes-for-localization

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am understanding your request right, but I believe this is the scope you are looking for:

A generalized route which can receive the "locale" based on which you can serve the page in the appropriate language.

If that's the case, I would define a route like this:

```
Route::get({locale}/home, 'HomeController@index');
```

and then in your HomeController@index, you will have $locale variable based on which you can implement your language logic:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed (View or Redirect)
     */
    public function index(Request $request, $locale)
    {
        switch ($locale) {
        case 'en':
            //do english logic
            break;
        so on...
        }
    }
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: thats exactly what i have right now, please refresh the page and see my comment on dilip hirapara's answer. Sorry it is me who spelled the question wrong. thank you for your answer though